# Nintex SharePoint 2010: Why does my loop finish before the criteria is met?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, nintex-workflow

I have created a simple workflow which loops every 5 minutes until two fields on the current item are no longer "empty" eg.

Loop while: value 1 is empty AND value 2 is empty

The loop ends once value 1 is populated and value 2 is still empty. I've tried a few different variants on this loop, and I get a variation of results none of which match the actual criteria.

I've tried:

workflow 1 status is not "completed" AND workflow 2 status is not "completed"

workflow 1 status equals "In progress" AND workflow 2 status equals "In progress"

I have even tried reversing the logic, however this just exits the loop immediately.

Comment: You might need to elaborate on this as you might not even need to use workflow for that. 
What is updating those two values? 
What happens once the condition is met?

Comment: Are the fields that you're checking workflow status fields? If so, you'll want to check them for the underlying number values of the various statuses, not the text that displays in them. Also, looping repeatedly on an item while waiting for fields to change does seem like an odd approach, and might get you in trouble with the safe looping setting for Nintex workflows in central admin (which is meant to prevent infinite loops before they begin). You could use a pause action, or use a scheduled site workflow instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround it by querying the list for the field content into a variable and than counting the number of characters in the variable using inline function varLenght. Result 0 means the field is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Logic issue if I understand correctly.

While (A is empty AND B is empty) will finish if either one of A or B is not empty.

While (A is empty OR B is empty) will only finish once both A and B are not empty.